# Return status code with an authorization filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to check if the access token is in the blacklist, and then return Unauthorized.

```
public class CheckBannedTokenAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    public Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (TokenInBlackList("232322323"))
        {
            //context.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting any error(s)? What's your end goal?

Comment: @Abbas I don't know what return

Comment: Are you not sure about what is going to be return type of your function `OnAuthorizationAsync`

Comment: Why do this check in authorization? Why not do it earlier in authentication?

Comment: @Tratcher I don't see authentication filters in Core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#filter-types

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @Tratcher I don't find any useful resource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that you need to fill `context.Result`. Cause you want to return `401 Unauthorized` as response, use built-in `UnauthorizedResult` class:

```
if (TokenInBlackList("232322323"))
{
   context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
   return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

In general, this is the same as `new StatusCodeResult(401)`

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the classic "401 Unauthorized" that you expect.

```
async Task IAsyncAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    ClaimsPrincipal user = context.HttpContext.User;

    if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        context.Result = new ChallengeResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your code seems all good, simply initialize the `Response` and return `Task`

```
if (TokenInBlackList("232322323")){
    context.Response = context.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```